# Elixir OTP based application architecture

Tags: architecture, elixir, erlang-otp

I study Elixir, for example decided to make an application for ping the list of proxies. The essence of this is that you need to periodically download a link from the list with a proxy, and in many threads ping this list, leaving only a live proxy. As I see it:

There is a supervisor of pinger processes. Each pinger knows his configuration (timeout for ping and stuff). Once launched, the pinger sends a message to the importer process "give me a proxy for ping" and waits for a response.

There is an importer supervisor. The importer accepts a message asking to give out a proxy for ping, and if his proxy list is empty, he answers the pinger "as long as there is no proxy," and downloads a list of new proxies. After that, waiting for messages from pingers. After receiving the message, he sends info about the proxy pinger. Pinger does his job, sends a message to the importer with the result of ping. The importer stores the proxy.

Is this scheme optimal? It is planned that the pingers will be no more than 1000, but not less than 500. Is it proper to build a proxy for ping and return the result through messages between processes? Will the importer manage to respond to messages from pingers? Or is it better to let the importer download the proxy list, for example, in redis, and the pingers themselves take a proxy for ping from there and process the result themselves?

Comment: Optimal in what way? Using least memory? Executing in the shortest time? Have you tried your proposed solution to see if there are any obvious problems with it?

Comment: I've read this question 3 times its still unclear what you are trying to accomplish. How often are the pings? What is done with the ping results? What does "leaving a live proxy" mean?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, No, I have not yet tested any of the options. Optimal - to be carried out in the shortest possible time. But in general, I'm interested in doing it right if the import process takes about 200 messages per second. I do not have much design experience, so I do not know how to solve such problems

Comment: @StevePallen, Pings are made constantly. That is, the pinger process always requests a new proxy and pings it. If the proxy is a worker, it is stored in Redis. If it is bad, it is removed

Comment: I don't believe there is an "optimal" way to accomplish what you are doing. That's what I mean--try your approach and see what happens. If you have problems then post questions about the specific problems.

Comment: Where does the list  come from and how often does it change?

Comment: The list is taken from several servers, updated approximately every 15 minutes

Comment: I would like to suggest GenStage too. It's a perfect fit for batch jobs. And by using it, and fitting your jobs into the stages, you are doing the right thing, OTP-wise and performance-wise.

Comment: Unless I've missed something in the requirements of this solution, I don't think GenStage is going to offer any value here. Handling read frequencies of 15 - 20 seconds and total of 500 - 1000 pings is pretty small scale. But perhaps I'm still missing something from the problem writeup. Perhaps my answer will flush out the details a bit more.

Comment: @StevePallen, About quantity - on the average in one sheet contains about 20,000 proxies. There are now 3 such sheets, maybe more. The number of simultaneous pings for one sheet is limited to 1000 per second. Probably, I do not understand my task quite clearly, because I do not know much English and I have to use an online translator. I think that I understood your answer, and I will try the real

Comment: Ok, that is much needed information. The question is about rate limiting and I agree, [GenStage](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage) is probably the way to go. Please take a look at `GenStage` and get back to us if you need additional help with the architecture.